# How to count elements length by name only not display none using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to count elements length by name only not `display:none` using javascript ?

i want to count elements length by `getElementsByName` only that not `display:none` using.

this below code, it's count all `name="test[]"` and it's alert `5`

I want to count `name="test[]"` only not display none (`result will be 3`). How can i do that ?

```
<div name="test[]"></div>
<div name="test[]"></div>
<div name="test[]"></div>
<div name="test[]" style="display: none;"></div>
<div name="test[]" style="display: none;"></div>

<script>
var test = document.getElementsByName("test[]");
alert (test.length);
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lp6sn3w4/

Comment: Get the elements with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), like so: `document.querySelectorAll("[name^=test]:not([style*=none])");`.

Comment: :not([style*=none]) will match on any style property/value that has none in it.  IE: that will match background: none

Comment: Umh... A more accurate selector would be `'[name=test\\[\\]]:not([style*="display: none"])'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the nodes and check their styles.  To easily iterate over the nodes, you need to first convert the NodeList (you get that back from `getElementsByName`) to a regular array.  You can then filter by the display style value and get the length of the array:

```
var test = document.getElementsByName("test[]");
var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(test);

nodes.filter(function(node) {
  return node.style.display !== "none"
}).length
```

Comment: how to get result in this case 3

Comment: var result = nodes.filter(function(node) {
  return node.style.display !== "none"
}).length

Comment: Not general enough. We should use `getComputedStyle` to get display, if `display:none;` is defined in `<style>`. Therefore, it may be a better idea to dynamically add or remove items for further js management.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparison for the style and display property of a node.

```js
var test = document.getElementsByName("test[]"),
    count = Array.prototype.slice.call(test).reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + +(a.style.display !== 'none');
    }, 0);

document.write(count);
```